# Upgrading class library project to .net standard 2.1 where this has been referenced by .net framework 4.X projects

Tags: c#, .net

We are upgrading our solution of multiple projects. Starting with one class library which is been referenced by 13 projects. I need to upgrade my class library project `.NET Framework 4.5` to `.NET Standard 2.1`.
Here the problem is:

**This class library is being referenced by projects of `.NET Framework 4.5` and its throwing error that it can't access `.NET Standard 2.1` lib**

> Project 'abc.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'.

How to resolve this problem? Upgrading all those 13 projects is not possible at the same time.

---

EDIT:
Following comments, if I convert lib to `.netstandard1.1` then errors start coming in the library itself:
[image]

After downgrading lib to `.netstandard1.1`, following on
[NetStandard 1.4 does not allow decorating class with [DataContract]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950931/netstandard-1-4-does-not-allow-decorating-class-with-datacontract). I saw this post and added this package `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives`:
[image]

I even added reference to older dll but, still getting error: [image]

Comment: Well, per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) it seems that `.NET Standard 2.1` is not following along with `.NET Framework`. Latest you can get is `.NET Standard 2.0` with `.NET Framework 4.6.1`.

Comment: So if all applications are at `.NET Framework 4.5`, you should upgrade your class library to version `.NET Standard 1.1`. This should work, once you upgrade also all other applications to the standard, you might upgrade everything again to the higher veresion of .NET Standard.

Comment: Changing it to `.NET Standard 1.1` also brings some issues. As you are mentioning another error, answer for this can be found in NuGet package, that must be downloaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950931/netstandard-1-4-does-not-allow-decorating-class-with-datacontract for more details.

Comment: I've just created 2 projects (one with `.NET Framework 4.5`, other `.NET Standard 1.1`). In library I have `[DataMember]` on some properties, VS asked me to download Nuget pckg:  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives` (version 4.3.0). After doing that, I was normally able to build it. Please try to run **build solution and provide with the output**.

Comment: Now the problem is that your "end application" and "library" is both using those serializations -> but they are using different version of DLL. One is coming from Nuget, other from "system assembly". What you need to do is remove all references to system assembly (`System.Runtime.Serialization`) and use Nugets everywhere instead.

Answer (score 2):

Adding answer as we've iterated through the comments. At first OP wanted to change framework of library to `.NET Standard 2.1` while having other apps under `.NET Framework 4.5`.

Unfortunately, this is not possible. As specified in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), `.NET Standard 2.1` is not following along with `.NET Framework`. Latest you can get is `.NET Standard 2.0` with `.NET Framework 4.6.1`. Solution for this issue is to downgrade common library project to `.NET Standard 1.1`, other app projects should be able to link to this.

Next iteration (after downgrading to `.NET Standard 1.1`) brought issue related to "unknown classes" and VS/compiler asking for adding reference. There was already [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950931/netstandard-1-4-does-not-allow-decorating-class-with-datacontract), answer is to download NuGet package related to the data serializers.

If your code in end-applications are also using classes/attributes from the affected assembly, you must make a cleanup. So that all code references the only single version of source. It is not possible to have one `Attribute` taken from Nuget and check for "same attribute/same name" but from different source (system assembly -> `System.Runtime.Serialization`).

Comment: Or, you know, upgrade the .NET Framework projects to 4.8. Framework 4.5 is more than four years old and [support will end as of April 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework). Upgrading to 4.8 will give you security updates and give access to .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Well, OP mentions that upgrading of all projects altogether is not possible. That's why I'm going this way. :/